# Public ,Private,классы, для чего они нужны именно в c# дайте пример

Tags: c#, классы

Для чего служат классы? Дайте пожалуйста наглядный пример работы класса,не понимаю для чего он.
Как можно поподробнее пж.Только начал обучаться,многого не знаю!
 public class/public string name/для чего они именно нужны,можно же просто создать переменную в program /зачем в классе делать это?

Comment: А не нужны, пользуйтесь private-классами, когда понадобится public — поймете. Если у вас приложение относительно простое, то public-классы могут и не понадобиться. Но когда вам понадобятся классы, которые должны быть доступны не только в одном текущем проекте, но и в других — вот тогда вам и надо будет делать их public. Ну и собственно по этой причине для всяких сторонних сериализаторов необходимо чтобы класс был public, иначе он с ним работать не сможет.

Comment: Можно пожалуйста подборнее ? зачем тогда приват...

Comment: Если вы пишете библиотеку классов, и кто то потом будет её использовать, то разделение на public/private помогает вам контроллировать, какие классы вашей библиотеки будут общедоступны, а какие нет

Comment: У вас это уже второй вопрос, который относится к ооочень базовым вещам, если что-то не понятно, то могу лишь порекомендовать Metanit, просто загуглите и поймете, что ничего сложного в поиске, в гугле нет.

Comment: У вас заголовок не соответствует телу вопроса. Про что именно вопрос: зачем нужны _классы_ или зачем нужны _модификаторы_ доступа?

Comment: Классы.именно классы)

Comment: Для чего нужны классы? Для всего. В C# все что есть – это классы.

Comment: Тогда зачем в заголовке присутствуют слова Public, Private?

Comment: не понимаю как поставить правильно вопрос,мне нужно чтоб они вместе были. public class/public string name/для чего они именно нужны,можно же просто создать переменную в program /зачем в классе делать это?

Comment: @Molnya А если будет тысяча переменных? А десять тысяч? Все в `program`?

Comment: Понятно. Сейчас ваш вопрос на уровне: "Для чего в русском языке слова? Можно же просто писать буквы". Просто продолжайте изучение языка. Читайте книги, документацию, пишите код. Со временем придёт понимание.

Comment: Между прочим, `Program` - это тоже класс.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы в конструктор (LEGO например) когда-нибудь играли?

Ну, так вот и создание программ подобно сборке конструктора, только в отличие от готового конструктора, купленного в магазине, детальки и кубики которого создает и продает производитель, вы самостоятельно придумываете и создаете виртуальные кубики и детальки. `Класс` - это, считай, чертеж кубика, а `Объект` - кубик созданный по этому чертежу. По одному чертежу может быть создано необходимое количество одинаковых кубиков. Объект - это считай функциональный блок программы

Язык `C#` изначально спроектирован так, чтоб программист работал в парадигме объектно-ориентированного программирования. Потому вам, волей-неволей придется перестроить способ своего мышления под использование классов.

Private, public - разграничение доступа к членам класса, подробнее читайте в книгах или документации.

Comment: Не хватает только аналогии компилятора с 3D-принтером для кубиков и сборщиком модельки в одном лице =) В остальном почти также приходилось объяснять на вводных лекциях, когда еще занимался подобным, не слово в слово, но очень близко =)